# c pointers and ctypes

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes

So, I have C++ class that I wrap in C so I can use it in Python using ctypes.
Declaration of C++ class:

```
// Test.h
class Test
{
public:
   static double Add(double a, double b);
};


//Test.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test.h"

double Test::Add(double a, double b)
{
   return a + b;
}
```

C wrap:

```
// cdll.h
#ifndef WRAPDLL_EXPORTS
#define WRAPDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define WRAPDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#include "Test.h"
extern "C"
{
   WRAPDLL_API struct TestC;

   WRAPDLL_API TestC* newTest();
   WRAPDLL_API double AddC(TestC* pc, double a, double b);
}

//cdll.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cdll.h"

TestC* newTest()
{
   return (TestC*) new Test;
}

double AddC(TestC* pc, double a, double b)
{
   return ((Test*)pc)->Add(a, b);
}
```

Python script:

```
import ctypes
t = ctypes.cdll('../Debug/cdll.dll')
a = t.newTest()
t.AddC(a, 2, 3)
```

Result of t.AddC(a, 2, 3) is always some negative integer.
There is a problem with a pointer, but I do not know what is a problem.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Show us your complete C and C++ code.

Comment: I edited the question, now there is complete C and C++ code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `AddC` is a static function the pointer is not your problem.

You need to pass `double` values to `AddC`, and get a double type back:

```
t.AddC.restype = c_double
t.AddC(a, c_double(2), c_double(3))
```

The [documentation for ctype](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) explains all this.

Answer (score 1):

[As stated in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#return-types)

> By default functions are assumed to return the C int type. Other return types can be specified by setting the `restype` attribute of the function object.

So just add

```
t.AddC.restype = c_double
t.AddC(a, 2.0, 3.0)
```

and you'll get `5.0` instead.

Comment: 2 and 3 are probably passed as integers, so the result might not be 5.0.

Comment: Oh right, that's true. Thanks. Maybe one should set `argtypes` as well.

Comment: Actually you have to do it like this